# How to prevent a nested WPF popup from closing after an off-screen click

Tags: wpf, wpftoolkit

Easiest way to explain the problem is with some Xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="NestedPopups.MainWindow" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" Title="MainWindow" Height="300" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <ToggleButton x:Name="b1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="50" Height="50"></ToggleButton>
    <Popup IsOpen="{Binding ElementName=b1, Path=IsChecked}" PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=b1}" Width="100" StaysOpen="False"
           Height="200">
        <Grid>
            <DatePicker HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
            </DatePicker>
        </Grid>
    </Popup>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

When selecting a date using the date picker, if the date selected does not overlap the window edge I get the desired behaviour i.e. The popup stays open. If the date selected is located past the window edge (any date on the bottom two rows) the popup closes.  What is the best way to prevent this behaviour?

Comment: Try setting `StaysOpen="True"` for `Popup`.

Comment: I only want the popup to stay open as I dismiss the DateTime picker.  I can set StaysOpen to true in between CalendarOpened/CalendarClosed events which seems to work but was hoping there might be a solution without code behind.  An IsOpen property on the Calendar would be handy...

Comment: Can you screenshot and post the behavior you are experiencing?